# Javascript HTML select dropdown

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, html-select

I am trying to get the data from database and display it in select option through drop down menu. I am getting the data correctly in java script page as well. But it is not displaying in the drop down menu of html.

HTML code:

```
<td>Organization Name:</td>
<td>
    <select id="orgname" name="Oname" onload="getOrganizationname();">
        <option selected disabled value=" ">Choose your Organization</option>

        <!-- <option value="1" >xyz</option>
        <option value="2">Brocade</option>
        <option value="3">Citrix</option> --> 
    </select>
</td>
```

Javascript code: function getOrganizationname() {

```
$.get('getOrganizationname.jsp',function(data)
{
    document.getElementById("orgname").innerHTML= data;
        alert(data);
    }
    );
}
```

Onload I am getting this in alert msg(trying to debug)

This is the information from the database:

```
<option value="Infosys"></option>
<option value="Akamai"></option>
<option value="Brocade"></option>
<option value="XYZ"></option>
<option value="XYZ1"></option>
<option value="XYZ2"></option>
```

Comment: onload i am getting this in alert msg(trying to debug) This is info. from database:
<option value="Infosys"></option>
<option value="Akamai"></option>
<option value="Brocade"></option>
<option value="XYZ"></option>
<option value="XYZ1"></option>
<option value="XYZ2"></option>

Comment: So watever data i am getting as value, I want to it to be between the option like : <option value="Infosys">Infosys</option>....... like this

Comment: You're use of `$.get` would appear to be jQuery. Is this correct? If so, I'll tag your question as such...

Answer (score 1):

You use use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get('getOrganizationname.jsp',function(data){
        $("#orgname").html(data);
    });
})
```

So your code now becomes:

```
<td>Organization Name:</td>
<td>
    <select id="orgname" name="Oname">
        <option selected disabled value=" ">Choose your Organization</option>
    </select>
</td>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get('getOrganizationname.jsp',function(data){
        $("#orgname").html(data);
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

After you got data and set it, does your html looks like this?
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ryLaxV

If yes, the problem is that you haven't text inside your options.

```
<option value="Infosys"></option>
```

should become

```
<option value="Infosys">Infosys</option>
```

How to?

```
var jData = $(data) // create jquery wrapped dom elements

// now iterate them and add text from values
jData.each(function () {
  var currentElement = $(this) // that's jquery way...
  var value = currentElement.val()
  currentElement.text(value)
})
// finally append it to the select element
$('#orgname').html(jData)
```

Also, consider the suggestion of using `$(document).ready` by Shakti Phartiyal.

And please, use `console.log(data)` for debug. To see the console - right mouse click on your page --> inspect element.

P.S. it would be much better, if you got raw data from server, I mean a json or something like that! :)